# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck on boot

Tags: boot, nvidia

I have ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (just upgraded), with dual boot system. Since lately I can not get ubuntu to boot. It gets stuck after grub menu - with black screen and only one line:
Ubuntu: clean, 100936/2949120 files, 9304228/11796400 blocks.

I read similar threads here on Ask ubuntu and it seems to be some kind od video graphics problem. It is the same with new and older kernels.

Also worth mentioning: during upgrade I had to remove xserver-xorg-video and colord package.

After some research I found out I have Radeon HD 4650 and not Nvidia graphic card. This seems to be connected with removed xserver-xorg.-video package?

```
ubuntu-drivers device
```

does nothing

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

gets me error: unmet dependencies (xorg-video-abi-24 and xserver-xorg-core (but it is not going to be installed)). Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

does nothing

Update: I managed to install Radeon driver and xserver-xorg-video-nouveau + colord packages. I did it inside normal boot (in recovery boot I somehow couldn't get internet connection). So I have all installed, but problem is the same. I get stuck on boot.

I also tried editing grub menu in linux line - adding nomodeset, nouveau.noaccel=1 and replacing "quiet splash" with noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll. No result.

Please help me, I can not use ubuntu.

Comment: I did almost anything from that thread, but no result

Comment: boot into recovery mode ... at its menu pick to connect to network ... then pick root prompt ... then run ...  `sudo apt purge 'nvidia-*'`  ... then run  `ubuntu-drivers devices`  to list available graphics drivers ... you should see  `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`  if so issue  `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`   .... above will remove nvidia and give you the open source nouveau driver ... reboot and you should be OK

Comment: I get error when installing xserver...unmet dependencies (xorg-video-abi-24 and xserver-xorg-core (but it is not going to be installed)). Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: update your question ( not as comment ) with output of running ...  `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`    ...  then install the package(s) it lists ... then reissue above mentioned xserver-xxx

Comment: I get nothing from running that...

Answer (score 2):

What finally solved my problem, was installing gdm3 package, which was "broken or not fully installed". I had to do it from normal boot and not revovery.

Now I got system settings and all back:)

Comment: how did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

just user live pendrive and install boor repair

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I get error: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: reinstall ubuntu with proper partitions .

Comment: How would that influence on my ubuntu files, settings,...?

Answer (score 0):

A good strategy is to discard all proprietary graphics drivers ( nvidia ) and revert to using the tried and true open source drivers ( nouveau ) ... so lets boot into recovery mode ... at its menu ... pick to connect to network

then pick root prompt ... then run

```
sudo apt purge 'nvidia-*'

sudo apt-get autoremove  # critical step to remove all libnvidia*
```

to confirm all nvidia packages are gone issue

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia  #  commandA
```

if above shows any packages then remove them too ... as per

```
apt-get purge xxxxxx  #  where xxxxx is an nvidia package listed commandA
```

do above command for each package listed in output of above commandA ... then run

```
ubuntu-drivers devices #  to list available graphics drivers
```

you should see `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` if so issue

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

if you see `Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages` then issue

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

this will list the held packages

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

then install the package(s) it lists ... then reissue above mentioned xserver-xxx

reboot and you should be OK ... issue this to confirm what video driver you are using

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

PS.  I just took a perfectly happy laptop which was using nvidia and did above steps to cut over to using nouveau and it worked just fine - no held or broken packages

Comment: First time I got message after sudo apt-get - f install, that I have package that it is no more needed (libxnvctrl0) and to do sudo apt autoremove. I did that and now after sudo apt-get -f install I don't get anything. But xserver-xorg... does not install (unmet dependencies: xorg-video-abi-24, xserver-xorg-core (is not gling to be installed) and recommends libgl1gmesa-dri (is not going to be installed))...

Comment: @Mersault  see updated steps I just added `sudo apt-get autoremove` which is critical see above

Comment: Did everything again with autoremove. Same result. My video shows RV730 (Radeon HD 4650) with configuration field only latency=0 and no drivers.

Comment: checkout https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation