# Letters all scrambeld - only 4

Tags: gnome, video, filename

I have latest ubuntu release (20.04) with gnome fallback session. After reboot I got all letters scrambled. On desktop, in terminal, in explorer all files have only first four letters. I don't know how to describe it better. In firefox it's alright, menus have all letters.

It's like that:
[image]

Update: I tried solution from that page: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1996836

I did:
sudo ppa-purge -d focal ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers

Result: I can not get to Ubuntu any more...it's stuck on boot, just like in my previous thread: [Ubuntu 20.04 stuck on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280830/ubuntu-20-04-stuck-on-boot/1281086?noredirect=1#comment2173972_1281086)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Both 20.04 and 20/10 can be called the latest.

Comment: I can not check in my system settings, because words have only 4 letters...

Comment: Well you can once this is fixed. Just keep that in mind for any future questions.

Comment: Others are also having this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328152/ubuntu-20-04-text-splitting-and-screen-flickering and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329037/after-software-update-text-display-only-4-letters

Comment: Also this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1328697/1157519

Comment: You can have an entirely functional command line to work on by using a virtual console. If you have GDM3 then the virtual console is Ctrl+Alt+F3, and can return back to the graphical session with Ctrl+Alt+F2. If you have lightdm, subtract 1 from the F keys, correspondingly.

Comment: I tried commands from the above link, but did not help. I also have Radeon graphic card...the link in french I can not understand

Comment: Now, to continue with repair attempts, you will need to use either a "safe graphics mode" (by editing the boot entry in the Grub menu (press `e` while it's highlighted) before pressing Enter on it (and adding the `nomodeset` param (before the part that says "quiet splash"))). All the while you are doing this, keep an eye at the text at the bottom of the Grub screen: it contains instructions. Or, alternatively, one could also use the "recovery mode", and its "drop to root shell" feature: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: Adding nomodeset doesn't help...I'm still stuck at boot...I can get terminal with CTRL-ALT-F3...problem is I can't install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau because of unmet dependencies (broken packages) xorg-video-abi-24 and xserver-xorg-core. I tried to install dependencies, but could not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem just like I did in the "stuck on boot" thread...I removed packages that were dependencies for xserver-xorg-video-nouveau, installed them, installed xserver-xorg-video-nouveau and instaled gdm3.