# After software update text display only 4 letters

Tags: updates

After regular software updates,Text doesn't display properly for system elements. Examples are shown below image.

Is this a bug with 20.04 updates? How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: After my "regular software updates," everything works properly, so it seems unlikely to be a bug. Check if the problem persists after a reboot.

Comment: I have the same issue. URL: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330100/only-the-first-four-letters-are-visible-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts

Answer (score 3):

I think this is same problem as [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328152/ubuntu-20-04-text-splitting-and-screen-flickering/1328913#1328913) to a similar problem.

I was able to fix it by removing the 3rd party AMD Radeon drivers I had previously installed (and had been working fine up until this morning when I did a SW package upgrade & rebooted). I ran the following commands and rebooted. Now my display is back to normal:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

Comment: Hi Peter, Your solution not working for me, Still I have the same issue.

Comment: I think I might have copy/pasted the wrong commands. I've updated my answer with the command I used to remove the 3rd party AMD Radeon drivers.

Comment: This solution also worked for me. Thank you!