# latest update created a real mess 20.04 only first 4 letters shown, windows are unreadable

Tags: gnome, graphics, xorg, fonts

One of the most recent software updates rendered my desktop nearly useless.  I can't even get into and work with the terminal since it became virtually unreadable.

I've searched thoroughly for suggestions.  I thought I found it with some tweak packages and turning off font antialiasing, but no luck there.  Another reply here suggested X11 issues.  But I can't really perform any of those because of the terminal issue.

Please help!!  what a horrible situation this is.

'''

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Turks PRO [Radeon HD 7570]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:39 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:efe20000-efe3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-d
```

'''

[image: screenshot, sorry forum won't allow me to embed yet]

[image: terminal unreadable]

[image: gnome tweaks of no help]

from the other questions and suggestions, I tried the following unsuccessfully:
'''

```
$sudo apt install ppa-purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ppa-purge is already the newest version (0.2.8+bzr63).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libffi7 libllvm11 libllvm6.0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
Updating packages lists
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
(base) tyle@B:~$
```

'''

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After software update text display only 4 letters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329037/after-software-update-text-display-only-4-letters)  or  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328152/ubuntu-20-04-text-splitting-and-screen-flickering/1328913#1328913

Comment: thanks for redirecting me.  Same problem indeed, somehow my search didn't find that one.  Sadly it didn't work for me, but i'm going to take the discussion over there

Comment: While I don't know the issue, you can access a virtual terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F7</kbd>. Log in by typing your username and password. You will be given a shell to run your terminal commands in.

Comment: Add information about your graphics card to your question - use "edit". You can copy/paste the output of `sudo lshw -class display` in your post, formatted as code.

Comment: I would love to, but my terminal is now unreadable.  I can't recall the graphics card.  I think it's an AMD.  oh, unless you mean copy the unreadable text from the terminal and paste it...that's clever.  let me try

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PC started having screen glitches after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331116/pc-started-having-screen-glitches-after-update)

Comment: no, no luck.  none of the links shared have done the trick to solve my problem unfortunately.